git checkout merged dev branch into main
I pulled a development branch to test on my test server, and when I switched back to main, it seemed like the development branch had automatically been merged into main.
First, I pulled the dev branch and then checked it out:
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git pull origin dev_branch
...
$ git checkout dev_branch
branch 'dev_branch' set up to track 'origin/dev_branch'.
Switched to a new branch 'dev_branch'

Then I tested and found out I have more changes to make. Tried returning the codebase back to the main branch:
$ git checkout main
Switched to branch 'main'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 6 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 6 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Is that expected? If not, what's the best way to test development code before merging?

Related: What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?

This is a well written question, but is also a dup, once you realize that "I pulled..." also means "I merged...". I have marked it as such.

The cause
The problem is that when you pulled dev_branch, you asked Git to merge it into main in your local sandbox.
The alternative scenario
What you should have done is a simple git fetch: that would have fetched new work on the remote, without merging anything. Then git checkout dev_branch would have worked as it did, but main would have still been where it was before.
The fix
Now, git status says your working tree was clean before you started, which means you can do what is sometimes a dangerous command: a hard reset.
git checkout main
git reset --hard origin/main

These two commands will checkout main again, and throw away all local work that has not been committed yet (you have no such work, so that's OK) and reset main to origin/main, throwing away the commits you accidentally merged in.
Understanding pull vs fetch
When you learn Git, you often learn to use git pull first. Don't. It's important to understand what git pull is: it's a shorthand for git fetch followed (blindly!) by a git merge.
My advice is to avoid git pull. Get used to typing git fetch and then looking at the history that got fetched with a tool that displays the commit tree. Maybe merging is what you'll want to do, if so, go ahead and run git merge. But maybe you have local commits you just want to add after the new commits you fetched: git rebase.
When you know you actually want to merge the remote changes in, sure, use the git pull shorthand.
